# SQL QUERY - using range of values with <= operator

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, database, oracle

I'm new to sql and I need your help with the below. Thank you so much in advance for your time!

Locprog table list the date in which a program was started at various locations (each location is identified by a unique indicator LOC)

```
LOC PROG DATE_STARTED   
121   P     10-JUL-95
131   P     11-JUL-95
141   P     18-APR-00
151   P     19-APR-00
161   P     26-MAY-06
171   P     28-MAY-06
181   P     30-APR-15
191   P     31-APR-15
192   P     19-JAN-16
195   P     20-JAN-16
```

DTWK table gives the week number associated with a particular date

```
D_IND       W_IND
09-JUL-95   199501
10-JUL-95   199502
11-JUL-95   199502
12-JUL-95   199502
13-JUL-95   199502
14-JUL-95   199502
15-JUL-95   199502
16-JUL-95   199502
17-JUL-95   199502
...        ...
18-APR-00   200005
19-APR-00   200005
26-MAY-06   200602
28-MAY-06   200602
30-APR-15   201504
31-APR-15   201504
19-JAN-16   201603
20-JAN-16   201603
```

Problem: I want to find the number of locations in which the program was active between weeks 200602 and 201603

I have tried

```
 select count(*) from (
 select distinct A.LOC, A.Date_started, B.w_ind as wk from Locprog A, DTWK B 
 where a.date_started=B.d_ind) aa
 where aa.wk<=200602
```

Answer:6

I'm having difficulties while trying to include the range of week (200602 and 201603) after the <= operator and then grouping by the 
 required range of w_id

```
 select count(*), bb.wek from (
  select distinct A.LOC, A.Date_started, B.w_ind as wk from Locprog A, DTWK B 
  where a.date_started=B.d_ind) aa
  where aa.wk<= ( select distinct W_ind as wek fromDTWK where W_ind between 200602 and 201603) bb
   group by bb.wk
   order by bb.wk
```

query does not work. Can you please help? Thank you!

The desired output

```
 wk       count
 200602    6
 201504    8    
 201603   10
```

Comment: Try: 
SELECT COUNT(LOC) FROM LOCPROG WHERE DATE_STARTED IN 
(SELECT D_IND FROM DTWK WHERE W_IND BETWEEN 200602 AND 201603) GROUP BY LOC;

Comment: Why isn't it just `WHERE aa.wk BETWEEN 200602 AND 201603`?

Comment: Would would be the desired output based on your sample data?

Comment: It's unclear why you want to use a comparison operator like `<=` with a list of week numbers returned by the subquery. What is it supposed to be less than?

Comment: is it mysql or oracle? you have both tagged

Comment: @smozgur,Barmar ,PM 77-1 the desired output is 
   200602    6
201504    8  
201603    10

Comment: @smozgur,Barmar ,PM 77-1 the desired output is                                                          
 wk       count
200602    6
201504    8 
201603    10
Smozgur and Barmur , if I go for between or IN i would get the count of  programs active for that particular week only which is wk       count
200602    2
201504    2  
201603    2
however, there are six locations where the program is active when wk<=200602.

Comment: It is Oracle , the intermediate table would beLOC PROG DATE_STARTED  W_Ind 
121   P     10-JUL-95  199502 
131   P     11-JUL-95  199502 
141   P     18-APR-00  200005 
151   P     19-APR-00  200005
161   P     26-MAY-06  200602
171   P     28-MAY-06  200602
181   P     30-APR-15  201504
191   P     31-APR-15  201504
192   P     19-JAN-16  201603
195   P     20-JAN-16  201603

Comment: Then drop the mysql tag and use on style join

Answer (score 0, accepted):

DTWK table has many records for each week number.
The following query gives start+end dates for each week number:

```
SELECT min( D_IND ) start_date,
       max( D_IND ) end_date
FROM DTWK d
WHERE d.W_IND between 200602 and 201603
GROUP BY W_IND
```

and a result of this query can be joined to LOC table to calculate a count:

```
SELECT count( distinct loc )
FROM LOC l
JOIN (
    SELECT min( D_IND ) start_date,
           max( D_IND ) end_date
    FROM DTWK d
    WHERE d.W_IND between 200602 and 201603
    GROUP BY W_IND
) x
ON l.date_started between x.start_date and x.end_date
;
```

Demo: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/a08af/6

Comment: dtwk appears to be inconsisent.  Compare 199502 to 2016*.  my first assumption was one entry per day in the week, but I dunno.

Comment: @ David Bachmann Jeppesen thank you very much for pointing that - I missed that there are many dates for each week. I changed my answer, but the query remain the same - it should work in both cases.

Comment: Anytime - although I deleted my comment, because I missed a detail myself. Your answer would still only work if you are confident that the DTWK table contains all dates OR that it contains all dates within the LogProg table, in which both cases, my answer would also work. It gets a little more complicated if this can not be guaranteed...

Comment: Thank you @Kordirko ! I got the required result with slight modifications to your answer

Comment: SELECT X.wk, count( distinct loc )
FROM LOC l
JOIN (
    SELECT d.W_IND as wk, min( D_IND ) start_date,
           max( D_IND ) end_date
    FROM DTWK d
    WHERE d.W_IND  between 200602 and 201603
    GROUP BY W_IND
) x
ON l.date_started <= x.end_date
group by x.wk
order by X.wk
;

Comment: Thank you @David for your comments and time

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT lp.loc)
FROM LogProg lp JOIN DTWK dw on lp.date_started = dw.d_ind
WHERE dw.w_ind >= 200602
AND dw.w_ind <= 201603;
```

Comment: I think you mean `<= 201603`.  Or just use `between`.  Although this doesn't work since you have to equal the date started, you probably want it to be any date after that.

Comment: Thankyou Donnie - fixed it! :)

Comment: See my edit.  Caught another problem, assuming I'm reading his table structure right.

Comment: By the way - I don't know about MySql, but with Oracle, you can always get the week-number from the date. You can easily find out how here on SO.

Comment: Donnie - can you describe what problem you found?

Comment: Assuming that the DTWK table contains all the dates in the LogProg table, this is my answer.